# Does the pullback metric preserve geodesic completeness?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $\pi: M \to N$ be an immersion. If $g$ is a Riemannian metric on $N$, then it follows the pullback $\pi^*g$ is a Riemannian metric on $M$. Suppose $(N,g)$ is geodesically complete. Does it follow $(M,\pi^*g)$ is geodesically complete? My first thought is yes. If $\gamma(.)$ is a unit speed geodesic on $M$, then $\pi \circ \gamma$ is a unit-speed geodesic on $N$. Since $(N,g)$ is complete, then $\pi \circ \gamma$ extends forever to an infinite length geodesic. Though, I am unable to understand if I can translate that back to the original geodesic $\gamma$ also extending forever.

Comment: There is no reason for the geodesics to be the same, even locally. Think of the circle embedded in the plane.

Comment: What do you mean? If $\gamma$ is a geodesic on $M$, then $\pi \circ \gamma$ is a geodesic on $N$, no?

Comment: No. A geodesic on $M$ (the circle) is a circular arc. A geodesic on $N$ (the plane) is a straight line. This would be true if $M$ is a totally geodesic submanifold, but it is rarely the case of an immersion.

Comment: Interesting. I was reading a source that wrote this, but I guess I misunderstood that.

Comment: Are you sure this source refers about generic immersions? Is there any chance that you might be mixing things up with other concepts like Riemannian submersions or so?

Comment: A local diffeomorphism $f: M\to (N,g)$ of connected manifolds is a covering map if and only if $f^*g$ is complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the inclusion $i : \mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\} \to \mathbb{R}^n$. The Euclidean metric $g$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is geodesically complete, but $i^*g$ is not.

Comment: That is an obvious counter example. Thank you. I'm curious what properties would imply the pullback metric is complete.